# Removing Data-Dependence from Loop

Tags: c++, loops

I have the following C++ loop:

```
for (i = LEN_MAX - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            int j = i - LEN_MAX + len;      
            if (j < 0)
                break;
            int ind = a.getElem(j);
            short t = ind;
            ind = --c[ind];
            b.setElem(ind, t);
}
```

What I would like to do is remove all dependency between iterations from it. In the above loop, for example, the line `ind = --c[ind]` has an inter-iteration dependency, because to decrease, I need to have the value from the previous iteration. Here is an example of the transformation I'm looking for:

From:

```
        for (i = 1; i < RADIX_MAX; i++) {
            if (i == radix)
                break;
            c[i] += c[i - 1];
            c[i] += temp;       
        }
```

To:

```
        short temp = c[0];
        for (i = 1; i < RADIX_MAX; i++) {
            if (i == radix)
                break;
            c[i] += temp;     //this loop no longer depends on last iteration 
            temp = c[i];
        }
```

I want to apply this same technique to the first loop I posted, but I'm not sure how. The reason I want to do this is because it is required in order to optimize the performance of a tool I am using. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Where did you get that example from? I fail to see how you removed the dependency. You may have gotten rid of c=c[i-1], but it is still entirely dependent on the previous iteration of the loop because the value of temp is set in the previous iteration.

Comment: Where does len come from?

Comment: Have you actually looked at the code generated by the compiler? I've found that, whenever it's reasonable, the compiler will do a fairly good job of shuffling/unrolling loops so that tight dependencies between loops are avoided.

Comment: Also, I would worry more about the fact that you are using `ind` as an index for the next line (well, `short t = ind;` doesn't count, as that would most likely be a single mov instruction into a new register, although changing size from `int` to `short` may add to that burden).

Comment: @2to1mux To give me a better idea of what to do, how can I correctly remove the inter-iteration dependency in the second example?

Comment: @JohnRoberts There isn't any way to completely remove dependency from previous iterations. To optimize your second example for purposes of parallelism would require something like a reduction (http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/1.1-Beta/x86_website/projects/reduction/doc/reduction.pdf).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no simple transformation of the loop you provided to remove the inter-iteration dependency (And the second example you gave doesn't actually remove the inter-iteration dependency). Each iteration depends on what happened to `c` the previous iteration and there's just no way around that *with the current implementation*. If you know something about the algorithm and/or the values stored within `c` and/or the values within `a`, you may be able to rework the code to remove the order dependency, we just can't do it given the short segment of code you provided.

Comment: To give me a better idea of what to do, how can I correctly remove the inter-iteration dependency in the second example?